# Accessing title of a MPMediaItem from an array, returns nil, although there exists one

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mpmediaitem, mpmediaitemcollection

Trying to save multiple playlists, and playback at a later time.

Here is the code, which configures the logic to display cell data.

```
let temp = rule?.valueForKey("music") as! NSArray
musicArray = temp as! [MPMediaItem]
print("musicArray = \(musicArray)=========>")
print(musicArray[0])
musicLabel.text = musicArray[0].title
```

Here is the error log,

```
musicArray = [<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x147e98ce0> 4230548632108111364, <MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x147dbdb90> 1821425359156734603, <MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x147dc3630> 5879796615610011657, <MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x147dc61c0> 1821425359156734604]=========>RuleViewCell
<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x147e98ce0> 4230548632108111364
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Maybe it's not the title.  What do you see if you print `musicLabel`?

Comment: print(musicArray[0])
print(musicLabel)
musicLabel.text = musicArray[0].title
<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x126686780> 4230548632108111364
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value......... I don't see anything at all..!!

Comment: So, if you **only** try to print `musicLabel`, you get nil.  (Is that correct?)  It sounds as if the problem is your controller outlet isn't hooked up right.

Comment: Not even "nil". There is literally nothing. No clue, but will check the outlets

Comment: But you're getting 'nil' in the error message, which makes sense if the outlet is defined as `var musicLabel: UILabel!` or something similar.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it is setup

Comment: Thanks @PhillipMills, there was a problem with the outlets. The connections seem to have broken for some reason. Sorted them all. Thanks again!